# Using outputText inside ui:repeat to get properties of ArrayList of objects

Tags: arraylist, jsf-2

I want to loop through an arrayList of objects, and show one of the properties using outputText. This is a sample of my managed bean:

```
@ManagedBean(name="post")
@SessionScoped
public class Post {
    private List<Post> posts = new ArrayList<Post>();
```

and this is the getter for my list:

```
public List<Post> getPosts() {
    if(posts.isEmpty())
        posts = utility.DBHelper.getPosts(statement);
    return posts;
}
```

Now I need to show the text property of my posts in my view:

```
<ui:repeat value="#{post.posts}" var="post">
    <li><h:outputText value="#{post.text}" /></li>
  </ui:repeat>
```

bur I am getting empty String as the result.
I have seen many solutions for ArrayList of String type, but this seems to be different.

Comment: This code looks perfectly fine. Something is missing in code you've attached or the values from your managed bean are simply empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change **var="post"** to **var="_post"**.

```
<ui:repeat value="#{post.posts}" var="_post">
    <li><h:outputText value="#{_post.text}" /></li>
</ui:repeat>
```